# Multiple private/public Key pairs in Tink

Tags: java, authentication, encryption, rsa, tink

I started exploring **"Tink"** recently and now stuck at a particular problem, and couldn't find the solution in docs or online.

The case is: ***I want to have two sets of Public/Private keypairs. One would be active and other would be disabled.***

What I did was to generate a **KeyHandle** like this and stored it in **AWS KMS**:

```
KeysetHandle pri = KeysetHandle.generateNew(SignatureKeyTemplates.ECDSA_P256);
KeysetHandle pub = privateKeySetHandle.getPublicKeysetHandle();

pri.write(JsonKeysetWriter.withFile(new File("pri_p")),
            new AwsKmsClient().withDefaultCredentials().getAead(keyStoreUrl));
pub.write(JsonKeysetWriter.withFile(new File("pub_p")),
            new AwsKmsClient().withDefaultCredentials().getAead("someUrl"));

//*************** Same code for secondary **************

KeysetHandle pri = KeysetHandle.generateNew(SignatureKeyTemplates.ECDSA_P256);
KeysetHandle pub = privateKeySetHandle.getPublicKeysetHandle();

pri.write(JsonKeysetWriter.withFile(new File("pri_s")),
            new AwsKmsClient().withDefaultCredentials().getAead(keyStoreUrl));
pub.write(JsonKeysetWriter.withFile(new File("pub_s")),
            new AwsKmsClient().withDefaultCredentials().getAead("someUrl"));
```

I did this because I thought that I'd generate two pairs and keep them in different json files as:

1. **'pri-p' (primary)**
2. **'pub-p' (primary)**
3. **'pri-s' (secondary)**
4. **'pub-s' (secondary)**

After doing this, I wrote an API which returned both public keys (primary & secondary) to the client and the response was:

```
({
"primaryKeyId": 12345,
"key": [{
    "keyData": {
        "typeUrl": "type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.EcdsaPrivateKey",
        "keyMaterialType": "ASYMMETRIC_PUBLIC",
        "value": "IDJNVUs,csaIQDP9jhF+MERyoZ6Ede/LteBYS0n4zVbYTcuCZCiFBERhyIhAJettefH3BPjFyyZC3m90Pw+m/K8sjiEPS"
    },
    "outputPrefixType": "TINK",
    "keyId": 12345,
    "status": "ENABLED"
}]
},{
"primaryKeyId": 6789,
"key": [{
    "keyData": {
        "typeUrl": "type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.EcdsaPublicKey",
        "keyMaterialType": "ASYMMETRIC_PUBLIC",
        "value": "EgYI7hfsdhfsdm0eeii3m43434334390439TcuCZCiFBERhyIhAJettefH3BPjFyyZC3m90Pw+m/K8sjiEPSXKSMgmWEgr"
    },
    "outputPrefixType": "TINK",
    "keyId": 6789,
    "status": "ENABLED"
}]
})
```

Now I wanted to make the secondary one as inactive so that nobody uses it, meaning **status: DISABLED** using the code as below:

```
KeysetHandle secondaryPublicKey = KeysetManager
            .withKeysetHandle(secondaryPublicKey)
            .disable(keySetHandle.getKeysetInfo().getPrimaryKeyId())
            .getKeysetHandle();
```

but I got the exception as:

```
java.security.generalsecurityexception: cannot disable the primary key
```

At that time, I realized that what I did was wrong, and I had to do it altogether again, so that both **Keys** are in the same **KeysetHandle** and this I am unable to do as when a KeysetHandle is created like:

```
KeysetHandle pri = KeysetHandle.generateNew(SignatureKeyTemplates.ECDSA_P256);
```

It's already marked as a primary key and if I retrieve the public key from this, that would also be primary key. No matter how many keys I generate, all will be marked as primary using this.

There's another way:

1. Create multiple **Key**
2. Add in **Keyset**
3. Mark one of them as primary
4. Create **KeysetHandle**
5. Write in AWS Kms

But I am not sure how to go about this, or is whether it is the correct way.

Need some help on this, I'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. A Keyset, by definition, can contain multiple keys. One of them is primary and the rest are active. The primary key can sign and verify, but the active ones only can verify.

Here's how you can do that:

1/ Generate a new KeysetHandle that contains two keys using [KeysetManger](http://google.github.io/tink/javadoc/tink/1.2.2/com/google/crypto/tink/KeysetManager.html):

```
KeysetManager km = KeysetManager.withEmptyKeyset();
// Add a primary key
km.rotate(SignatureKeyTemplates.ECDSA_P256);
// Add a secondary key
km.add(SignatureKeyTemplates.ECDSA_P256);
```

2/ Retrieve a KeysetHandle from the KeyManager

```
KeysetHandle kh = km.getKeyHandle()
```

3/ Encrypt and write it to a JSON file, as you did in your code.

Hope that helps,
Thai.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thai. What I don't understand that from where did you pass "kh" in the arguments.
KeysetManager km = KeysetManager.withEmptyKeyset(kh);

For this, do I need to create the keysetHandle first? If that's the case? Then what's the point of doing this? 

KeysetHandle kh = km.getKeyHandle()

Since I already be having a keyset handle.

Comment: Also it doesn't have "addNewKey()" method. The only method that I can find is "add()" which takes KeyTemplate as an argument. A version issue maybe? I am using 1.2.2

Comment: Muhammad: oh sorry, I didn't notice that addNewKey is private. Anyway I updated my sample code which now shows how to add two keys. Does this work for you?